# Captcha no carga en mi iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

estoy usando un `<iframe>` para mostrar esta página:

https://servicios.registrocivil.gob.ec/cdd/

Que me da un formulario con CAPTCHA. La página sale bien pero en el caso del CAPTCHA no me lo muestra, por ende no puedo seguir con el formulario.

Algún consejo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe
    src="https://servicios.registrocivil.gob.ec/cdd/"
    width="1300" height="500"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Request URL: https://servicios.registrocivil.gob.ec/cdd/Captcha.ashx 
Request Method: GET 
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error`, `ASP.NET 4.0.30319`

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de session. El Iframe carga la pagina bien. Pero el llamado desde la web principal que es otro dominio no tiene la session y el servidor retorna ASP.NET error 500.
Esta es la URL:
https://servicios.registrocivil.gob.ec/cdd/Captcha.ashx
Solo devuelve el recaptcha si se ingreso directamente desde el dominio principal. https://servicios.registrocivil.gob.ec/cdd/ > No via iframe.
Deberias de cambiar el modo de la sessión en ASP.NET

Comment: sin contar las casi 200 conexiones que hace el frame =P

Comment: Literalmente más de 200 conexiones de script y otras más por ahi.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu comentario, pero no tengo acceso al codigo de esa pagina como podria hacer ? no es posible por Js ?

Comment: No es posible desde el navegador. La única manera y no tan sencilla es que construyas el formulario de tu lado y desde tu servidor hacer proxy a la consulta tomando previamente la session del servidor remoto todo desde una pagina web dinamica del lado de tu servidor. Pero si es posible.

Comment: Pero heido que casi es imposible obtener la session del dominio de la pagina que esta en el iframe, algun consejo de como hacerlo ? y usar PHP o ASP.NET?